# Why do seam edges move together?

Tags: texturing

I have a cube where I am trying to move one UV edge that happens to be a seam. My understanding is that since the edge is marked as a seam, it should be separate from surrounding edges, but when I move the edge other vertices/edges move as well. Why does it do this? Specifically, since the edge is marked as a seem, shouldn't it be moving independently?

Thanks,
[image: Initial Scene - Seam Edge is selected]
[image: After moving the Edge, another edge and two other vertices move as well?!]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have the `Edge` Selection enabled (3 vertical line icon), as well as the `individual vertex` selected (3 white dots).

[image]

Comment: your help saved me a lot of time and frustration , thank you a loooot :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two modes for UV Editing.  One is called *Sync Selection* and so far as I know, the other one has no name.  Sync Selection is just *off*.

To me they are *modes* because they behave very differently.  Officially, they may just be considered the same mode with *Sync Selection* either *On* or *Off*. 
 Anyways, to the point.

In one of the modes; you will have the problem as described.
When you select a vertex along a seam then you will also be selecting the other vertices which are on the 3D mesh at that point.

Conceptually, *UV seams* are not spitting the vertices. 
Seams are cutting up the image texture.

If you look at the image Mike Pan posted; there is an icon at the bottom left which shows *a cube, two vertices, and a cursor arrow*.  That icon is how you change between modes.

For the image posted, the icon toggle is deactivated.

In that mode, to work on all the islands simultaneously, you must select everything in the 3D Viewport.
Now everything will also show up in the UV/Image Editor.  In this mode, the seam vertices will not affect one another when selected and moved.

Now if you activate *Sync Selection* using the icon mentioned; the vertices along other island seams will also be selected and moved when you move island-edge vertices which are connected on the 3D Mesh.

I have found that both modes can be very useful.  If you want to avoid the problem that you are having while staying in the mode that you are in; then you can hide the other vertices by selecting the faces they are connected to and pressing the *H* key.
Now they will not be affected when you move their corresponding vertices.

Or, use the other mode.

EDIT:Additional info requested

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marc :) It's my first time to use stackexchange  and I did not except to get such a detailed explanation! Just wanna say Thank you big times :)

Comment: Just a small question, you mentioned the words : island, island-edge, island seams in your post, does "island" just mean an independent set of edges/vertices or it's got more meaning technical than that?

Comment: The islands are groupings of UV coords. I'll add a screen capture to the answer above.

Comment: Once again Marc, thanks for your illustration, time and effort :) your help is very appreciated...